# SQL Server Query join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Two tables

Table A

```
TaskID  Description
1         One
2         Two
```

Table B

```
TaskID  DependentID
1          2
```

I want the desired output

```
1  One 2 Two
```

Comment: clarify the expected output data

Comment: How 1  One 2 Two is output? what are the column headers in output, and can you explain your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can get the desired output using query like following.

```
SELECT T1.TaskId, T1.Description, T3.TaskId AS DepTaskId,T3.Description as DepDescription  
FROM [TABLE A] T1
INNER JOIN [TABLE b] T2 ON T1.TaskId= T2.TaskId
INNER JOIN [TABLE A] T3 ON T3.TaskId= T2.DependentID
```

**Example Code**

```
DECLARE @TABLE_A TABLE(TaskId INT, Description VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE_A
SELECT 1,'One'

INSERT INTO @TABLE_A
SELECT 2, 'Two'

DECLARE @TABLE_B TABLE(TaskId INT,DependentID INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE_B
SELECT 1,2

SELECT T1.TaskId, T1.Description, 
            T3.TaskId AS DepTaskId,T3.Description as DepDescription  
FROM @TABLE_A T1
INNER JOIN @TABLE_B T2 ON T1.TaskId= T2.TaskId
INNER JOIN @TABLE_A T3 ON T3.TaskId= T2.DependentID
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| TaskId | Description | DepTaskId | DepDescription |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| 1      | One         | 2         | Two            |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
```